How to index a Realm model's property using TypeScript
I'm trying to index a string property on a Realm model using TypeScript.
I'm using Realm's React Native SDK with Realm's Expo example app.
Using the same example from Realm's docs:
class Book extends Realm.Object<Book> {
  name!: string;
  price?: number;

  static schema: ObjectSchema = {
    name: 'Book',
    properties: {
      name: {type: 'string', indexed: true},
      price: 'int?',
    },
  };
}

Results in the following error:
Classes extending Realm.Object cannot define their own `schema` static, 
all properties must be defined using TypeScript syntax


That code is correct so I would guess you're creating that object using the new operator elsewhere in your code instead of Realm.create(). Can you check that?

@Jay, the error is thrown at compile time, and I have not used the new operator to create an instance of Book.

In that case, the issue is either environmental, as in something is not set up correctly/other plugins/another Book extends, or being caused by code outside of what's in the question, as that code works so the issue is not duplicatable as-is. Do you have other plugins?

I'm using Realm's Expo example project and adding Realm's model example for indexing a property using TypeScript. The issue is totally duplicatable if you set up the Expo example provided by Realm, and add the example for indexing a model property using TypeScript to it.

Yes, that's what I did, and it's working correctly for me. I created a totally fresh project, stepped through the setup guide and ran the code.
